# Accessing metadata from azure storage blob

Tags: c#, azure, metadata

I can't seem to find a method to access individual blob metadata for blobs in Azure Storage.

FetchAttributes only works on the whole container. My method returns a list of blobs which match the parameters I set. I then need to iterate through that list and retrieve some metadata from each of those blobs but I am not finding any methods to do so.

It seems like a lot of overhead, but should I be Fetching those attributes when I create the container object, and then filtering for the blob list?

So, I figured I'd try that,

```
 public static IEnumerable<GalleryPhoto> GetGalleryPhotos(string folderPath)
 {

        var container = CreateAzureContainer(containerName, false);
        container.FetchAttributes();
        var blobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(folderPath);
        var photoGalleries = new List<GalleryPhoto>();
        var blobs = blobDirectory.ListBlobs().ToList();

       ...rest of code
  }
```

The blob objects in blobs, show 0 for the metadata count.
Each of the items HAVE metadata, verified by looking at the properties in Azure Storage Explorer for each blob.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It is entirely possible to fetch the metadata in result when listing blobs. What you would need to do is specify [`BlobListingDetails`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.bloblistingdetails.aspx) parameter in [`ListBlobs`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblobdirectory.listblobs.aspx) method call and specify `BlobListingDetails.Metadata` there. What this will do is include metadata for each blob in the response. So your code would be:

```
public static IEnumerable<GalleryPhoto> GetGalleryPhotos(string folderPath)
 {

        var container = CreateAzureContainer(containerName, false);
        container.FetchAttributes();
        var blobDirectory = container.GetDirectoryReference(folderPath);
        var photoGalleries = new List<GalleryPhoto>();
        var blobs = blobDirectory.ListBlobs(false, BlobListingDetails.Metadata).ToList();

       ...rest of code
  }
```

Do give this a try. It should work.

Answer (score 5):

```
var blobs = container.ListBlobs().OfType<CloudBlockBlob>().ToList();
foreach (var blob in blobs)
{
    blob.FetchAttributes(); //Now the metadata will be populated
}
```

See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.blob.cloudblockblob.fetchattributes%28v=azure.10%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396